# Does IRC 2012 Code allow water lines in exterior wall?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance

New construction, 2x6 exterior wall in a basement walkout. Does the IRC code or any plumbing code prohibit installation of water and drain lines in an exterior wall?  We want to put a vanity sink against an exterior wall in the basement. House is not built yet. We are in the planning stage for blue prints. No contractor yet. Don't want to plan for something we can't have.

Comment: If you have a builder, do they not know?

Comment: Doesn't your outdoor sillcock use plumbing in an exterior wall?